# How to configure your application on first run?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web-applications, authentication

I am confused here, and I don't know whether I am asking a foolish question. The scenario is this,
I have created an application in Development Environment and I want to deploy the application in Production therefore I emptied all the tables in the Database including the User. I don't have a registration page where I can add users. The Registration is done by the Administrator. As I Truncated the tables of users I don't have an administrator too. But at first run I need to create a Super Admin who can add users and configure the application.

1. We can do it in a way that when the application runs for the first time we can check whether the table is empty and if it is write a logic to create a user and login with the user details.

Is there any other logic for this Issue? Please correct me if I am doing it in a wrong way. I use Spring MVC and Hibernate for the development.

Comment: Do you have login page? What are you planning to achieve? When you see create user on application start for the first time, are you referring to Admin?

Comment: Yes, I do have a login page, the user here i mean an Administrator. Let me make it simple. How do you create an Administrator? Using direct entry to the Data Base table or Use the application?

Comment: If that is the case then I would recommend to have an admin user in DB already. Because it is really unnecessary to put a logic in your application to create admin user when application starts as it is one time activity.

Comment: ship the database with the records already inserted.

Comment: @Suyash Its not just a table of users, I have role and user-role relationship table and other supporting table for the users. And some of the fields has got encrypted data and the logic of the encryption is performed in the application.

Comment: @Zionz : That is ok. What I am saying is, you don't need to include DB script to create an admin user at the time of application start. Because all the roles and responsibilities for this user will remain same throughout application life-cycle. Then why to make your application bulky unnecessarily for this user. For normal user you will have your logic in your app.

Comment: @Suyash is this how the developers normally do?? And if I am inserting an Administrator Manually to the DB, how will I figure out the  Encrypted data fields? Or should I have the encrypted data also with me?? Please don't feel irritated am just a beginner.

Comment: There can be different approaches to it. 
1. You can have encrypted key with you which you will store in DB when creating admin in DB.
2. You can keep the encrypted credentials of admin in property file rather than DB and fetch it from there. This could help you to save some extra calls to DB.
3. You can have a DB procedure which handles this encryption for you whenever you insert new user with non-encrypted password.

There are some more approaches as well that can we worked out.
What I mean is, it depends on developer how it needs to be handled.

Comment: @Suyash thanks you!!

Answer (score 2):

Get access to the module where you have your application bootstrap, then register manually a super-user(admin) on the DB table.

Remember that you'll have to set a control if it already exists or you'll fill the table very fast ;) If you want, you could simply call a function that verify if the table is empty: if it is, just ask username and pw (if you register in this way an user), and just register the first user as super-user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already implemented this logic. I looking at more conventional way of doing it.Or is it the conventional way??

Comment: There are lots of ways to implement this, it's your only choice. But I think that 2 ways are more user-comfortable: the previous i said and this one: on starting the application you'll have to prepare a 'layer' or a 'first-target page' that is where you'll ask username and pw to your first super-user. Everytime another user will be added it will come as normal user. The problem is: if you want to implement (as i think) this application as multi-user in same istance, you'll have to check if there is already an admin at target page, and the FIRST user who open the istance will be admin

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this by implementing WebApplication initialiser.

Add the following class to your project

```
public class SpringDispatcherConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(ApplicationConfig.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(ApplicationConfig.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("SpringDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/*");
    }

}
```

And then you need ApplicationEventListnerClass and annotated method gets triggered on application start where you can implement functionality to create user

```
@Component
public class ApplicationStartListener {


    @EventListener
    public void handleContextRefresh(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

        String id = event.getApplicationContext().getId();
        if (id.startsWith("org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext:") && !id.endsWith("SpringDispatcher")) {
            //implement your on startup functionality here

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have implemented the same logic in another way.